# Python - connecting with twitter's API

Tags: python, api, twitter

I wrote a script to connect to twitter's API. 
This script works perfect on my PC. 
Here is the script, that grabs all the tweets with the word 'car' in them:

```
from tweepy.streaming import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import StreamListener


ckey='myCustomerKey'
csecret='myCustomerSecret'
atoken='myToken'
asecret='mySecret'

class listener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self,data):
        print data
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print status

auth=OAuthHandler(ckey,csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)
twitterStream=Stream(auth, listener())
twitterStream.filter(track=['car'])
```

As I said, it works perfect on my machine. 
But, when I copied this script to an external server (and of course, downloaded the relevant module (tweepy))- I get this error:

```
runfile('Z:/Data/twitter/grab_tweets.py', wdir='Z:/Data/twitter')
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-5-74327b031634>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('Z:/Data/twitter/grab_tweets.py', wdir='Z:/Data/twitter')

File "C:\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 685, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 71, in execfile
exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)

File "Z:/Data/twitter/grab_tweets.py", line 25, in <module>
   twitterStream.filter(track=['car'])

File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\tweepy\streaming.py", line 445, in filter
    self._start(async)

File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\tweepy\streaming.py", line 361, in _start
self._run()

File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\tweepy\streaming.py", line 294, in _run
raise exception

ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(10053, 'An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine')
```

I looked this error up - I saw something about firewall, so I tried to turn it off- but it didn't help.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You need to authenticate with your proxy server. I'm not sure if that is possible with tweepy.

You could try using [TwitterAPI](https://github.com/geduldig/TwitterAPI) which supports proxy authentication. See [doc](http://geduldig.github.io/TwitterAPI/authentication.html).

Comment: first of all, thank you! second, I didn't figure out how I should add the proxy_host auth to my code.

Comment: @beni I haven't seen a solution for authenticating Tweepy with a proxy server either. That's why I suggested looking at something besides Tweepy.